# TESTRPC install ERR from npm Node.js

Tags: node.js, solidity

I am pretty new to node.js and this is my first install using npm. I got a lot of ERR Lines which I am not sure whats going wrong with it.

I was trying to install TESTRPC in my OS X. just installed node js and using command

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

but i got ERROR message

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates 
--mirror https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git 
/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-
git-master-df3f1ce1: Cloning into bare repository 
'/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-
js-git-master-df3f1ce1'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates 
--mirror https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git 
/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-
git-master-df3f1ce1: remote: Repository not found.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates 
--mirror https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git 
/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-
git-master-df3f1ce1: fatal: repository 
'https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git/' not found
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" 
"ethereumjs-testrpc"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/dion/.npm/_git-
remotes/_templates --mirror https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git 
/Users/dion/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-
git-master-df3f1ce1
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/dion/.npm/_git-
remotes/git-https-github-com-debris-bignumber-js-git-master-
df3f1ce1'...
npm ERR! remote: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: repository 
'https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git/' not found
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dion/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from one of the dependencies testRPC is using. 
To be more precise Bignumber.js i think what happened is the developers added it by cloning the ssh link instead of https probably it's a forked version that's why.

Either it got solved now probably by the developers on their own so you just install it and it's perfect. 
Or you use an older version that doesn't have this problem.

Or you manually clone the project change package.json and refrence bignumber.js by it's https link removing the .git in the end then run npm install